# Search for a substring which ends in a varying integer

Tags: c#, string

Take this scenario.

I have a string that can sometimes end in `" - C(N)"` where `(N)` is a varying positive *integer*.

How would you validate whether the string contains that sort of substring or not? I thought this was an interesting case and I would like to see how people would tackle it in the most tidy and efficient ways. (I am using *C#*)

For e.g.

`"ABC - CA"` would return false

`"ABC - C20"` would return true

Comment: You need to use a regular expression for this

Comment: Would `ABC2` return true or false?

Comment: @Oscar I think that is the tidiest and most efficient way to do it.

Comment: @MattJones false it needs to be " - C2" if (N) was 2

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using *regular expressions*:

```
string source = "ABC - C20";

bool result = Regex.IsMatch(source, " - C[0-9]+$");
```

Comment: This seems so far the better way. but what if the substring is at the beginning or at the middle of the string and not at the end?

Comment: @Jurgen Cuschieri: that's why I've put `$` *anchor* for the match to be in the *end* of the line

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
int result = 0;
var success = Int32.TryParse(yourString.Substring(yourString.LastIndexOf(" - C") + 4), out result);

if(result <= 0){
    success = false;
}
```

Comment: Counter example: `"ABC - C-3"` since `-3` is a valid integer; another counter example (an *eerie* one) `"ABC - C9876543210"` when `9876543210` is a valid integer it's above `int32.MaxValue`

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko - And as -3 is a valid integer, then all should be fine.

Comment: In my case I forgot to add that it can only be a positive integer. My bad... Edited question.

Comment: Please, change `.IndexOf` to the `.LastIndexOf` as well: or `"ABC - C123 bla-bla-bla"` will be a counter example.

Comment: Done. Good call =)

Comment: Shorter form is `var success = Int32.TryParse(yourString.Substring(yourString.LastIndexOf(" - C") + 4), out result) && result >= 0;` - no need in `if`; typo: `Substring`; or (in case of **c# 7.0**) even `var success = Int32.TryParse(yourString.Substring(yourString.LastIndexOf(" - C") + 4), out var result) && result >= 0;` - we don't want to declare `result` outside

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                                "ABC - CA",
                                "ABC - C20"
                            };

            string pattern = @"\w+\s+-\s+\w+\d+$";

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input : '{0}' Matches : '{1}'", input, Regex.IsMatch(input,pattern) == true ? "True" : "False");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score -2):

In excel (VBA) you can find the last character is alpha or not.

=ISALPHA(RIGHT(String, 1) will give true for ABC - CA and false for ABC - C20

You can adapt the solution with C# by using appropriate syntax

Comment: No, there is not such ISALPHA function available in .Net